# IIFE across multiple files

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, iife

Is there anyway to have javascript code defined in 2 or more separate files to run in the same IIFE?  I'm open to using build tools like gulp to accomplish this.

It just seems like such a mundane problem.  I want my code to be organized and separated into their own files (distinct knockout view models, by the way).  But I want them all to run in the same function and not pollute global.

Comment: Sure.  Choosing the tool you want to use is beyond the scope of Stack Overflow (it would be opinion based), but yes - you can concat files to do this.  Knockout itself [uses these fragments](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/tree/master/build/fragments) for just that purpose.

Comment: Yes!  I've seen these fragments and knew it was possible.  And it seems super trivial to concat all the files together and surround it with an IIFE (perhaps using gulp-concat).  But then the problem is developing in Chrome.  I want to still be able to use chrome's dev tools to make changes to code on the fly.  And making them on a generated js file wouldn't work, I need to be able to modify the original files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modern way to do this is to use *modules* rather than try to put everything into an IIFE. Right now, using modules means using a module bundler like RequireJS, SystemJS, Webpack, Browserify, etc. In the medium-term future, you'll be able to use ES2015+ modules directly in the browser if you like, or again use bundlers to bundle them into a single file. (You can use ES2015+ module *syntax* today with transpilers like Babel, but you still need a bundler.)

You've mentioned you're using RequireJS at the moment but not using its `define` functionality. Just for the purposes of illustration, here's *roughly* how you'd define a module (I'm not a fan of Require's syntax, but you can use Babel to transpile ES2015 syntax to it):

Say I have a module that defines a KO component:

```
define("my-component", ["ko"], function(ko) {
    // ...define the component...

    // Return it
    return MyComponent;
});
```

That:

1. Says the module is called `my-component` (module names are optional, so for instance the top-level module of an app needn't have a name)
2. Says it depends on the module `ko` (which provides Knockout); note how that dependency is then provided as an argument to the callback that you use to define your module
3. Returns `MyComponent` as the top-level thing defined by the module

Then in my app:

```
define(["my-component", "another-component"], function(MyComponent, AnotherComponent) {
    // use MyComponent and AnotherComponent here
});
```

You can also have modules that group together other modules that are commonly used in groups, to simplify things.

In ES2015+ syntax instead:

`my-component.js`:

```
import ko from "./ko";
// ...define MyComponent...
export default MyComponent;
```

`app.js`:

```
import MyComponent from "./my-component";
import AnotherComponent from "./another-component";

// ...use them...
```

Obviously, both examples are **very** simplified and there's a lot more you can do.

Comment: Thank you!  I am using RequireJS to import all of my files.  I'm not using any define() functionality, purely using it to get javascript files into the browser via require().  I tried consulting the documentation to get all of these files into an IIFE, but came up short.

Comment: @smulz: Sorry, I should have been more clear: You *don't* put everything all in one IIFE. Instead, you define things in modules (in which you do not create globals), and you use `require` and `define` (in the case of RequireJS) to pull the things you need from one module into another. These bundlers they have a tool you can have it use at build time that walks the dependency tree and builds a single file with all the dependencies in it (which doesn't create unnecessary globals). E.g., the modern way to do what you're doing with IIFEs is to use modules *instead*.

Comment: @smulz: So when developing, the bundler brings in the files individually, which is handy for developing. When ready to publish, you run a build, which runs the bundler's dependency tree inspection and combines the files into one deliverable.

Comment: Thanks TJ.  I think I understand.  I guess I was hoping for a solution that doesn't require huge amounts of refactoring.  But this seems like the correct solution.

Comment: And thank you for the detailed example.  Very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is two separate issues.

1. Can an IIFE span multiple files - NO!
2. Can classes/functions/etc in multiple files NOT polute global scope - YES!

file1

```
var myNS = {};
```

file2

```
myNS.MyViewModel = function(){ ... }
```

file3

```
myNS.OtherViewModel = function() { ... }
```

As a very simplistic example, of which there are 101 ways to achieve the same.

Comment: Yes, this was my original approach to the issue.  I wasn't a huge fan because of the huge amounts of code to refactor to add "myNS" to every object instantiation.  I'm beginning to think I don't have any other option.

Comment: @smulz: You do: Modules.

Comment: @smulz to be clear, this is an old-fashioned answer. T.J. is by far and away more correct in the modern sense.